# How to save child field using @RequestBody in spring-boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, one-to-many

I have parent and child classes.
Parent have a field:

```java
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<Child> childs;
```

Child

```java
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Parent parent;
```

My controller

```java
    @PostMapping("/parent)
    public Parent createParent(@RequestBody Parent parent) {
        return parentRepo.save(parent);
    }
```

it saves parent and childs info EXCEPT parent_id in the child table. parent_id is always null. Is it possible to workaround this problem without deleting mappedBy="parent" option and using additional tables?

Comment: Your mapping is broken

Comment: Can you upload the JSON you are sending?